# Need help to delete icons from Applications Menu

Tags: release-hera, applications, wine, menu, folder

I had installed AWS Workspaces, a .msi file through wine. It was installed successfully but didn't run the way I had expected so I uninstalled it through wine uninstaller but the icon still appears on the application menu. How can I remove it from there? I have AppEditor but I don't want to just hide it, I want to know why it is there even after uninstalling and how I can remove it permanently. From my end I have gone into .wine folder in home directory and removed all folders related to this app. Am I missing something?

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Hi Ementary newbie here. How do I get to the local dirrectory! Cannot find in files! Please help, old icons that I also need to delete! Thanks Ash

Answer (score 3):

These are stored under `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs`. Go and delete 'em.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. i really appreciate your help.:)